# How to allow user to select notification sound from default sounds in Settings.app?

Tags: ios, push-notification, settings.bundle

I'm wondering if it's possible to allow the user to change the push notification sound for my app in Settings.app->Notifications to any of the default sounds (similar to how the alert tone for Messages can be changed there). If so, what do I need to change in code to allow this? Do I need to change the Settings.bundle?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the name of the sound file chosen by the user to your server (along will the device token) and store it in your DB. When you send a push notification to that user's device, you'll fetch the sound file name from the DB and put it in the `sound` property of the notification payload.

If the user doesn't choose a specific sound, you can send a default sound file name in the notification payload.

Comment: This is helpful, but how do you populate the list of sound files the user can choose from to include the default sounds on their device?

Comment: @Vic Can't help you with that. I have no idea.

Comment: After creating the collection of sound files from the app bundle, add one more for 'default' manually. It doesn't matter what you call it, as long as it is not the name of an actual sound file in the bundle. If you specify a sound that does not exist, iOS will play the default/built-in sound.